# Loop In Google App Script To Retrieve Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use an addon (Supermetrics) to retrieve hourly conversion rate data in a Google spreadsheet.

[![Supermetrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF4RE.png)

After each hour, it adds the conversion rate to the correct line (in the screenshot, It'll add the conversion rate to 15).

I have modified an existing script to send an alert via e-mail when our conversion rate is going down on our website.

Problem is, my script aim a static cell (B3) but I would like it to be looping so it can retrieve the conversion rate hour after hour:

15, then
16, then,
17, then, etc.

Here's the code:

```
function ConvRateChecker() {
// Fetch hourly conversion rate
var conversionRateRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MyReport").getRange("B3"); 
var conversionRate = conversionRateRange.getValue();

// Check conversion rate
if (conversionRate < 0.80){

// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2:B8");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

// Send Alert using e-mail in HTML
var options = {}
options.htmlBody = 'Hi everyone,<br /> <br />The conversion rate on XXXXX <font color="red">dropped to ' + conversionRate + '%' + '</font> ' + 'at ' + timeDay + ':00.' + '<br /> <br />Please check your <a href=\"https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report-home/">Google Analytics</a> account as soon as possible.';
var subject = '(WARNING) Conversion Rate Dropped';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', options);
}
}
```

Comment: you want to loop down the column or row? Or are you trying to use the value in B3 as the start index? So if B3 is 10 then you'd like to go from 10, 9, 8, 7, etc? I'm confused about where you want to loop?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St I would like to loop the script starting right bellow the empty cell (in my screenshot, the script would select B12, then B13, etc. And it will start over at B26).

Comment: I had to make some changes to make your post more readable, could you re-do the screenshot with the row numbers, would make it a bit easier to follow. Having trouble if you mean up by your HOURS or the actual index, cause B26 is under 0 hour so I assume you want it to go from the top to bottom if I'm correct?

Comment: lopping through the sheet should be trivial but I believe your actually asking how to continue from the last empty row hour after hour? I would create a range and then look for the empty value from the last cell and add to above it (check if it's empty!) and add this to a trigger that runs every hour. Is this the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St I reuploaded the image. And yes, this is what I am trying to solve!

Comment: Here are the docs on triggers for Google Apps. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: @KyleCalica-St I'll read that, it looks very interesting. However, I found the solution using a simple trick with the Google sheet, no script editing required: =INDEX(B3:B26,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B3:B26),0)) It will return the latest non blank cell in the range!

Comment: ahh yes I thought you wanted a Google App Script to do so this will return it and you can set it in Google App Scripts, then use the trigger to automatically grab based on the outcome of this.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St well I was complicating things I believe when easier solution where available. Thanks so much for your time Kyle!

Answer (score 0):

### If you are still looking for an Apps Script solution for finding the last cell of a coherent data range in the desired direction - use [getNextDataCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)

Sample:

```
var conversionRateRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MyReport").getRange("B26").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP); 
var conversionRate = conversionRateRange.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ziganotschka ! However, if it reaches B3 and come back to B23, how would it work?

Comment: After it reaches B3 and comes back to B23 - will the cells B3 to B22 be empty again? What the function does is to find the cell on the edge between a range with contents and an empty range. Same as if you select a cell in the sheet and then press "CTRL"+"arrow up".